# Extracting class dependencies from Eclipse project using Rascal

Tags: java, rascal

I am using Rascal to analyze an Eclipse Java project and identify the class dependencies in this project. To be more precise: class A depends on class B if and only if class A has a method which (1) uses a parameter of type B or (2) uses a local variable of type B. Here, I am only interested in dependency relations A -> B, where A and B are **both** classes within my project and are both **different** classes. I already created an M3 model from my Eclipse project and was able to identify the required parameters (of type B), using the following:

```
{ <e.name, f> | e <- model@declarations, e.name.scheme == "java+parameter", f <- model@typeDependency[e.name], !(/java/ := f.path), f.scheme != "java+primitiveType" }
```

Here, I obtain all declarations of my M3 model, filter on parameters and using the `@typeDependency` annotation I retrieve the corresponding type (I didn't know how to manipulate the information I obtained when using `@types` instead). Finally, I use the last two statements to filter out all parameters of which the type is not related to a class in my project, like String and Integer parameters. As I am quite new to Rascal, I could not think of another way to achieve this.

My question now is: how can I retrieve the local variables of type B for my project? Using the scheme `"java+variable"` is not sufficient in combination with `@typeDependency`, as this also includes variables of type Iterator or String that have a dependency with other classes within my project and I am not interested in these types of variables. Moreover, the resulting set contains variables like

```
B b = field.method();
```

where `field` is a global variable within that class. Because of this, a type dependency is present from `b` to the class itself and I would like to exclude these from my result as well. So, I believe that `@typeDependency` does not give me the information that I need.

I found [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16165699/how-to-get-types-and-names-of-variables-in-a-java-project) that seems to deal with local variables with Rascal, but it uses AST instead of M3. I am not sure how to use AST in this setting (like I said, I'm just a beginner in Rascal) and was wondering if it could be done with M3. How should I proceed?

**Edit:** in order to clearify what I want to achieve exactly, I will give a small example. Say that my project has two classes, `A` and `B`, and `B` contains some methods (`methodB1`, `methodB2`, ...). 
Moreover, class `A` has the following structure:

```
class A {

   void methodA1(){
        B importantVar;
        importantVar.methodB1();
        ...
        String someVar1 = importantVar.methodB2();
        int someVar2 = importantVar.methodB3();
   }

   void methodA2(){
        A someVar3;
        ...
   }

}
```

The variable that I would like to be able to retrieve is `importantVar`, because it is a local variable and it is of a type `B` (a class within my project). I am not interested in `someVar1` and in `someVar2`, because they are local variables that have a type that is not related to my project. In the code example that I gave earlier for the parameters, I filtered these types out with the last two statements. Moreover, I am also not interested in `someVar3`, because it has type `A` and occurs within this same class.

I think that I should be able to retrieve the local variables that I want using `@types`, but I am not sure how. When using `@types`, I get a `TypeSymbol` and I already looked into the definition of this data type to see how I could manipulate it. Most of the data types within `TypeSymbol` have a location named `decl`, of which I know how to manipulate it. The problem is however, that I also receive some types that do not have this location, like `\int()` and `\array(..)` for instance. In these cases, the location `decl` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to analyse a specific `TypeSymbol`, use pattern matching. Here is an example.

```
TypeSymbol t;
if (class(l,_) := t) {
  println(l);
}
```

or in a comprehension

```
{ l | <_,class(l,_)> <- m3@types};
```

or as part of a lookup in a comprehension:

```
{ <v, l> | <_,v> <- m3@containment, isVariable(v), class(l,_) <- m3@types[v]};
```

Comment: This indeed solves the problem I had with `@types`, so thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `containment` relation from the M3 model. All local variables are declared in the `declarations` relation, but they also appear in `containment`. If you want to get all the variables in a method `m`, you can have a look at `containment[m]` and filter on the `java+variable` scheme.

Interesting corner cases are when a method contains an anonymous class. You have to look at bit further in `containment` (like a transitive closure) if you need to filter nested variables used in 
anonymous nested classes as well.

By the way, the M3 model has utility predicates `isVariable`, `isClass`, etc. and also `classes(M3)`, etc.

Comment: I am aware that the containment relation can be used in this setting, but it also gives me variables I don't want. For instance, I get local variables like `String x = ...` back, and I am only interested in finding dependency relations A -> B, where A and B are **both** classes within my project. So, I would like to exclude this `x` from my result. I'm sorry if this wasn't clear from my question, I have updated it now to include this.

Comment: Ok. I believe the answer by Davy below should help!