# Parse error on pattern matching

Tags: rascal

I was writing a little helper function `toString(TypeSymbol t, M3 m)` when I encountered a weird parser error.

The function has a lot of statements like:

```
...
}else if(object() := t){
    return "object";
}else if(float() := t){
    return "float";
}else if(double() := t){
    return "double";
...
```

These work fine.
However, when I try this same pattern for `int()` or `void()`, the compiler gives an error, specifically on the `=` sign.

```
if(int() := t){}
          ^ Parse error here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it often happens, I found the answer to this question while I was typing it up.
However, I think it'll be valuable for others so I will post it nonetheless.

I got the syntax for pattern matching in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929342/451847

It seems that the 'proper' way of pattern matching is to prefix the type you want to test for with a `\`.

So, the code above becomes:

```
...
}else if(\object() := t){
    return "object";
}else if(\float() := t){
    return "float";
}else if(\double() := t){
    return "double";
...
```

The non-`\` syntax works for most of the cases but I think `int()` and `void()` have a different definition.

Comment: You need the \ in cases where the name you are using is also part of the Rascal syntax. In this case, object, float, and double are not, while both int and void are names of Rascal types.